# What are Abūjh Muhūrtas?

Tags: scripture, belief, practice, astrology

Several times, in the newspapers, TV, magazines, etc., the term - ***Abūjh Muhūrta*** *( अबूझ मुहूर्त  )* is commonly encountered,  especially in reference to performing some new auspicious works, like marriages,  *upanayana or yajñopavīta saṃskāra*, et al.

*{ If in need of some primitive type rough translation of the term, one may, for the sake of language convenience may translate it as **Infallible/Inextinguishable Auspicious Moments (or Day)**.}*

The commonly told  *Abūjh Muhūrta*, as per various outlets that I have heard and [read](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=fc5Qlerh_6sC&pg=PA43&dq=abujh%20muhurat&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic09HGu7TvAhUYA3IKHQv2CVoQ6AEwBnoECAgQAw#v=onepage&q=abujh%20muhurat&f=false) are -

- Hindu Nava Vārṣa: Guḍi Parva/Ugadi (Caitra Śukla Pratipadā) - हिन्दु नव वर्ष: गुड़ी पड़वा/ उगादि ( चैत्र शुक्ल प्रतिपदा)
- Akṣaya Tṛtīyā - अक्षय तृतीया
- Rāma Navamī - राम नवमी
- Deva Prabodhinī Ekādaśī - देव प्रबोधिनी एकादशी
- Daśaharā - दशहरा
- Basanta Pañcamī - बसंत पंचमी
- Phūlera Dūj ( Mīna Saṅkrānti)  - फूलेरा दूज (मीन संक्रांति)
- et al.

Various [sources](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m-hindi.webdunia.com/astrology-articles/shubh-muhurat-117053100028_1.html%3Famp=1) gives different combinations of the above days in their lists of *Abūjh Muhūrta*, with some even going to the extent of giving statements like *"there are [3.5 days](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m-hindi.webdunia.com/astrology-articles/shubh-muhurat-116042100037_1.html%3Famp=1) only to be counted as infallible, i.e., just half part of a certain auspicious day"*.

The ***basic premise as per astrology being, that all kinds of auspicious rites can be performed on these infallible days***, without any need or worry about any kind of  bad effects of planetary - *graha* combinational afflictions, like *tribala (त्रिबल)* - which relates with *surya*, *soma* & *Bṛhaspati*, or *udaya - asta* periods of *Bṛhaspati* & *Śukra*, etc., and thus no need of consulting *pañcāṅga - पंचांग*   to decide on any auspicious *Muhūrta*, since those auspicious days are self qualified, i.e., *Sarva Svayaṃ Siddha (सर्व स्वयं सिद्ध)*.

---

**So finally, the Questions are:**

1. **What are the scriptural sources for *Abūjh Muhūrta* or Infallible Auspicious Days ? How and why they have been decided on? Any specific Puranic or any kind of other scripture account like some boons?**
2. **What's the astrology - *Jyotiṣa Śāstra (ज्योतिष शास्त्र)* view on this as per standard texts on *Jyotiṣa Śāstra*?**

Comment: To many questions

Comment: @DarkKnight, :D

Comment: What do you mean ":D"

Comment: It's a smiley. Lol

Comment: Okay. :) thanks lol

Comment: @DarkKnight My pleasure! :))