# Story of Lord Shani's sibling Bhadrā (भद्रा )?

Tags: scripture, belief, astrology, surya, shani

*Yama*, *Yami* (personification of the river Yamuna) and the *Aśvinī Kumāra*, are popularly referred as the siblings of Lord *Śani* (*शनिदेव* ) .

What **might** be lesser known, are *Bhadrā (भद्रा )* and, [*Tapatī*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapati) (*तपती* ) are also Shani's siblings.
Again, *Tapatī* maybe understood as the personification of the [Tapti (or Tapi)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapti_River) river. The starting lineage of *[Kuru](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_characters_in_the_Mahabharata#Kuru)* can be traced to her.

*Bhadrā* is more shrouded in mystery, to even place her as some deity or other exalted entity. As a guess, I have heard from the elders and [read](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kPJsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&dq=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%20%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%20%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFoqzUnLfvAhXFb30KHfGFBmUQ6AEwAHoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%20%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%20%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE&f=false) a [lot](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Gays70sSp_YC&pg=PA30&dq=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%20%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%20%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFoqzUnLfvAhXFb30KHfGFBmUQ6AEwAnoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%20%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%20%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE&f=false), is the concept of a recurring inauspicious time frame, which is also called as *[Bhadrā - kāl](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.amarujala.com/amp/astrology/what-is-bhadra-in-astrology-know-bhadra-muhurat) (भद्रा - काल)*.

> Generally, to begin any new auspicious work, one has to make sure that all the
> planetary positions are appropriate and conducive, thus yielding a
> *Śhubh Muhūrta* i.e. A favourable or propitious period. All new works must be done on this propitious time frame, which is determined as per
> the *Pañcāṅga* calculations by a competent astrologer -
> *jyotiṣika*.  Now, if,  by chance the calculated propitious time frame coincides with a *Bhadrā - kāl*, then the propitious period is rendered inauspicious to either Start and End a new auspicious work. For example: Each year during *Rakṣābandhana*, a *Bhadrā - kāl*, is invariably observed, which forbids the *Rakṣāsutra* tying up ritual for that period of *Bhadrā*.

---

So, **two questions:-**

1. **Is the astrology *Bhadrā - kāl*, actually same as the Lord *Śani's* sister *Bhadrā* ? What are the actual valid scriptural references for the various stories (linked above) related to the origin and life of *Bhadrā*?**
2. **What happens when a *Bhadrā - kāl* happens in *Abūjh Muhūrta (A.B.)*? As I discuss in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45195/what-are-ab%C5%ABjh-muhu%CC%84rtas) question, that A.B, by definition  are infallible and *Bhadrā* by definition invalidates any kind of auspicious moments. So, won't it create a paradox? Or, is it that generally the A.B days are choosen such, that they don't fall on any *Bhadrā - kāl* days?**

Comment: Where is the mention that Bhadra is a daughter of Chhaya? Interesting information..

Comment: The way I understood Chhaya Devi's progeny is, she is a shadow of Sanjna, so just as Sanjna gave birth to a Manu, a God of Justice and a River Goddess, so did Chhaya Devi. Thus we have Vaivasvata - Savarni Manus, Shani - Yama deities of justice, and Yamuna - Tapati, river goddesses.

Comment: @Surya, yes, but what about *Bhadrã*?

Comment: yeah as I said, this is the first time I'm hearing about Bhadra.